# RasDial without szPhoneNumber

Tags: visual-c++

I want to migrate this command line

```
rasdial.exe VPN username password
```

to Visual C++

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <windows.h>
#include<Ras.h>

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{

    RASDIALPARAMS rdParams;
    rdParams.dwSize = sizeof(RASDIALPARAMS);

    lstrcpy(rdParams.szEntryName, L"VPN");
    lstrcpy(rdParams.szUserName, L"username");
    lstrcpy(rdParams.szPassword, L"password");

    HRASCONN hRasConn = NULL;
    int dwRet = RasDial(NULL, NULL, &rdParams, 0L, NULL, &hRasConn);

    return dwRet;
}
```

However it gives me an error code 723: The phone number, including prefix and suffix, is too long.

It is a PPTP VPN without phone number. How to fix it? Thank you for your help.